# React route render attribute type challenge typescript

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I have some component props called `project` passed through a `Link` to a `Route` like this (my project object goes in the `state` extended property):

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: path,
    state: {
      project,
    },
  }}
  key={project.id}
>
  <ProjectSummary project={project} deleteCallback={projectDelete}/>
</Link>
```

So then its received in the route and can be passed to the linked component like this:

```
<Route
  path='/project/:id'
  render={({ location }:any) => { //TYPE CHALLENGE HERE
    const { state } = location;
    return <ProjectDetails project={state.project} /> 
  }}
/>
```

Find the `any` type with the `//TYPE CHALLENGE HERE` comment .I tried lots of types of 'react-router' and 'react-router-dom' and it is impossible to find the matching type.

The closest seem this one:

```
export interface RouteComponentProps<
    Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {},
    C extends StaticContext = StaticContext,
    S = H.LocationState
> {
    history: H.History<S>;
    location: H.Location<S>;
    match: match<Params>;
    staticContext?: C;
}
```

As the component receives all the route params from this interface, but I extend the `location` where my project object is passed in.
In case it is of any relevance, this is the type of the `project` object I pass in:

```
export interface IFirebaseProject {
  id: string,
  authorFirstName: string,
  authorId: string,
  authorLastName: string
  content: string
  createdAt: firebase.firestore.Timestamp //firebase timestamp
  title: string
}
```

I post also the error I get with what I believe is the closest approach:

```
render={({ location }:RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, IFirebaseProject>) => {}
```

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: RouteProps | Readonly<RouteProps>): Route<RouteProps>', gave the following error.
    Type '({ location }: RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, IFirebaseProject>) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type '(props: RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>) => ReactNode'.
      Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
        Type 'RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, IFirebaseProject>'.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'IFirebaseProject'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: RouteProps, context: any): Route<RouteProps>', gave the following error.
    Type '({ location }: RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, IFirebaseProject>) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type '(props: RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>) => ReactNode'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(89, 5): The expected type comes from property 'render' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Route<RouteProps>> & Readonly<RouteProps> & Readonly<...>'
index.d.ts(89, 5): The expected type comes from property 'render' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Route<RouteProps>> & Readonly<RouteProps> & Readonly<...>'
```

Edit:

Updated screenShot of the log error in `render`:
[image]

Text full text of the error with the `render={({ location }: { location: Location<{ project: IFirebaseProject }> }) => {` attempt:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: RouteProps | Readonly<RouteProps>): Route<RouteProps>', gave the following error.
    Type '({ location }: { location: Location<{    project: IFirebaseProject;}>; }) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type '(props: RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>) => ReactNode'.
      Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
        Type 'RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>' is not assignable to type '{ location: Location<{ project: IFirebaseProject; }>; }'.
          Types of property 'location' are incompatible.
            Type 'Location<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Location<{ project: IFirebaseProject; }>'.
              Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ project: IFirebaseProject; }'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: RouteProps, context: any): Route<RouteProps>', gave the following error.
    Type '({ location }: { location: Location<{    project: IFirebaseProject;}>; }) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type '(props: RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>) => ReactNode'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(89, 5): The expected type comes from property 'render' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Route<RouteProps>> & Readonly<RouteProps> & Readonly<...>'
index.d.ts(89, 5): The expected type comes from property 'render' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Route<RouteProps>> & Readonly<RouteProps> & Readonly<...>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### RouteComponentProps

You are so close!  The `S` argument of `RouteComponentProps` controls the `state` type for both the `location` and the `history` props, so that **is** what you want to use.

The mistake is that you are setting `S` to `IFirebaseProject` which means that the state is itself an `IFirebaseProject`.  But in reality the state looks like `{project}`.  It is an object with a key `project` that has a value of `IFirebaseProject`.  So the correct type for `S` is `{project: IFirebaseProject}`.

With all of the types properly set, it is this:

```
render={({ location }: RouteComponentProps<{id: string}, StaticContext, {project: IFirebaseProject}>)  => {
```

But `location` doesn't use those other two generics, so this is fine:

```
render={({ location }: RouteComponentProps<any, any, {project: IFirebaseProject}>)  => {
```

#### Location

Personally I would just declare a type for the `location` property since that is the only property of the `RouteComponentProps` that you actually need.  I don't like using types which rely on generics that aren't used.

The underlying `Location` type comes from the history package which is a dependency of react-router.  Its types are imported into the react-router-dom types with `import * as H from "history"`, so that's why you see `H.Location`.  But you can import it directly:

```
import {Location} from "history";
```

And use it like this:

```
render={({ location }: {location: Location<{project: IFirebaseProject}>})  => {
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/nmq4ZN)

#### Edit: `render` vs. `component`

There is something strange going on in your CodeSandbox as I do see the error but I cannot reproduce it in isolation in the TS Playground.  Rather than banging our heads against the wall let's just use a slightly different approach that circumvents the error.

The `component` prop has a much more permissive type than `render` because it allows the props type to be either `RouteComponentProps<any>` (what we expect) or `any` (literally anything). Just switching the prop name from `render` to `component` makes it suddenly work!  We don't want to define a component inline because it will be [recreated on each render](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component), but we can define it externally.

We will now use the `component` prop for the `Route` instead of using a `render` function:

```
<Route path="/project/:id" component={ProjectScreen} />
```

There are two options for accessing the location in `ProjectScreen` which both seem to work for me.

1. We can access it through the injected props in the component.  This is exactly what we had before, but it is allowed on `component` and not `render` due to the `any` type on the props.

```
const ProjectScreen = ({ location }: { location: Location<{ project: IFirebaseProject }>; }) => {
  const { state } = location;
  return <ProjectDetails project={state.project} />;
};
```

2. We can access it through the router context by using the `useLocation` hook.  This hook is generic depending on state, so we can specify the state type when we call it.  We define a component that takes no props but renders the appropriate `ProjectDetails` based on the location from the hook.

```
const ProjectScreen = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation<{ project: IFirebaseProject }>();
  return <ProjectDetails project={state.project} />;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a complete answer. Find in the updated answer the screenshot + tenxt of the error I obtain in the `render` attribute. It seems that the type `(props: RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>) => ReactNode` is forced somewhere...but cannot get to find where. Thanks for any comments

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-wood-uifd0?file=/src/App.tsx) it is. Link to codesandbox project. the firebase configuration is missing  so there is a firebase error and the app does not render because I would not like to share firebase config of my app... The typescript compilation error shows in the App.tsx...many thanks for any comment...

Comment: I even tried `import { Route } from 'react-router';` instead of `'react-router-dom'`. No luck...haha....

Comment: It is so weird that I cannot reproduce the error in TS playground.  But you can circumvent it by accessing the location through hooks instead of props. `const ProjectScreen = () => {
  const {state} = useLocation<{ project: IFirebaseProject }>();
  return <ProjectDetails project={state.project} />;
}` `<Route path='/project/:id' component={ProjectScreen} />`.  I'm not getting any error in the sandbox with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I thinks I found the problem. I am positing an answer below. I will love to hear your comments if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

The `RouteProps` type is as follows:

```
export interface RouteProps {
    location?: H.Location;
    component?: React.ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any>> | React.ComponentType<any>;
    render?: (props: RouteComponentProps<any>) => React.ReactNode;
    children?: ((props: RouteChildrenProps<any>) => React.ReactNode) | React.ReactNode;
    path?: string | string[];
    exact?: boolean;
    sensitive?: boolean;
    strict?: boolean;
}
```

As the `render` attribute only defines the first argument, of `RouteChildrenProps` the other two that are not defined in its type are the default ones.
`StaticContext` for the second argument `C`, and for the third argument `S`, following down the type `H.LocationState` it ends up in `unknown`. Below the `RouteComponentProps` to follow this explanation:

```
export interface RouteComponentProps<
    Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {},
    C extends StaticContext = StaticContext,
    S = H.LocationState
> {
    history: H.History<S>;
    location: H.Location<S>;
    match: match<Params>;
    staticContext?: C;
}
```

The fix is to define the 3 possible arguments the render attribute can take in `RouteProps` like this: `render?: (props: RouteComponentProps<any,any,any>) => React.ReactNode;`, so that the second and third arguments of `RouteComponentProps` are not forced to their respective defaults.

This explains that type kind of being 'forced' in the `render` attribute, and the error I always obtained: `RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>' is not assignable to ...`

I am not that confident to assure that types are not correct in an external library, as I am not very experienced neither with react nor typescript, so would gladly hear any comment/caveat regarding this topic.

Comment: "As the render attribute only defines the first argument, of RouteChildrenProps the other two that are not defined in its type are the default ones."  This totally makes sense!  I just see the `<any>` and think "we can refine the types" but you're right, the `any` is only on one of the three arguments.